# 32bit exe on 64bit Python using py2exe

Tags: python, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, py2exe, 32-bit

I need to make an 32bit exe file using py2exe. The problem is that my machine and Python are 64bit. Is there some simple way how to make 32bit using 64bit Python and py2exe?

I heard that I should uninstall py2exe and install new py2exe 32bit, can this help me?

EDIT: If 32bit py2exe works, can I install 32bit py2exe next to my 64bit py2exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install the 32-bit python (in a separate directory, you can do it on the same machine).  Install 32-bit py2exe for this 32-bit Python installation plus all Python packages that you need. Then you can build a 32-bit eecutable.